# Symfony - entity data from other entity

Tags: symfony

I have entity `User`, which contains:

```
id | firstName | lastName | email
---+-----------+----------+----------+------
1  | John      | Doe      | superman@gmail.com
2  | Mark      | Greenman | green@o2.pl
```

and entity `Snapshot`:

```
id | firstName | lastName | user | date
---+-----------+----------+------+-----------
1  | Omar      | Doe      | 1    | 2015-05-12
2  | Jack      | Doe      | 1    | 2015-06-12
3  | Sam       | Greenman | 2    | 2015-03-12
4  | Frank     | Greenman | 2    | 2015-04-12
```

And I want to get collection `User[]` with names of specified data.

I have getters and setters function in `User` entity and I can put some code there, but I don't know how should I do it.

I can use relation to snaptshots, in repository get only snapshots for specified data and in getter do something like this:

```
public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->getSnapshots()[0]->getUser()->getFirstName();
}
```

...but it doesn't looks like good solution.

Comment: Why is it not a good solution? If it works the way you want it to work then its a perfect solution.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you need, what kind of conditions need to meet the users and where you need to use that., so us can help you.

Comment: IMO your best option is to add a specific method in either repository, depending on the data you need, and how you need it.